# C# HttpListener Digest authentication failed with forbidden (403) but works with Basic authentication

Tags: c#, httpserver, httplistener, digest-authentication

I have a simple HttpListener initialization with digest authentication:

```
this._listener = new HttpListener();
this._listener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:8001/");
this._listener.Realm = "Proxy Http Server";
this._listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Digest;
this._listener.Start();
HttpListenerContext ctx = await this._listener.GetContextAsync();
```

If I use `AuthenticationSchemes.Basic` or `AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate`, everything is works fine, I got the ctx.User with the identities, but when I use `AuthenticationSchemes.Digest` I always get a forbidden error (403) from the browser and doesn't get any `HttpListenerContext` back:

[image]

Comment: Sede following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/digestauthentication?force_isolation=true

Comment: But we do not have any IIS installed on windows. Is it possible that the digest auth only works with IIS?

Comment: Read entire page.  It works with Windows 8 as well.  What version of windows are you using?  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication

Comment: I have read it. In the "Windows 8 or Windows 8.1" section the 3rd point is that "Expand Internet Information Services", so the "Digest Authentication" feature is under IIS. ;)

Comment: My problem is not solved because, my and the end user PC doesn't have IIS, so I can't install "Digest Authentication" feature. :(

Comment: Digest Authentication should work in all versions of Windows except Win 11.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/win32/secauthn/microsoft-digest-authentication?force_isolation=true

Comment: I think, the Win 11 deprecation is "Microsoft Digest" not the simple Digest auth. The link said: "...accessing the services of a domain controller" so the Microsoft Digest is AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication I think.

So the conclusion: I have Windows 10 (x64) without IIS, but the AuthenticationSchemes.Digest is not working.

Comment: No. Windows Authentication and OAUTH is different from Digest.  I was reading that in one of my previous links.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I'm little confused the naming. I think Microsoft Digest also different from Digest. The System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes enum is netstandard2.0 so it can't be the Microsoft Digest, which will be deprecated. :) Now I'm really curious. :)

Comment: Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-authentication-methods